# Can the Mann Kendall Trend test be used on binary data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, trend, test-for-trend

If I have a dataset consisting of binary data e.g. (0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1), can I use the Mann-Kendall test to determine if there are an increasing or decreasing number of 1's?

(My question is less about wether or not this is the most appropriate test. I'm already also using gam(data ~ year, family="binomial"), which I consider more appropriate. However, suggestions for additional trend detection methods are also welcomed.)

Comment: Why not simulate that on random data and post the results here?